# cut the string using string as delimiter in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, cut

Need to print `libcom.so` by stripping out `1.0.0` when it prints first line.

```
#!/bin/sh
data=$(sed '0,/^__VERSION__$/d' "$0")
for d in $data
do
     echo with version:
     echo $d
     echo "with no version" 
     d1="$(cut -d\.so -f1 <<< $d)"
     #Need to save it in a variable for further processing
     echo $d1
done

exit

__VERSION__
libcom.so.1.0.0
libclock.so.1.0.0
libstdc++.so.6.0.20
libxml.so.2.7.8
libmi.so.1.0.0
librt.so.6.6.5
libcsapi.so.1.0.0
```

error out as `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Note that this is *not* a bash script. Even if your default shell is bash, using a shebang of `#!/bin/sh` causes bash to function in *POSIX compatibility mode*, in which many bash functions are unavailable.  `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is a reasonable default shebang, unless you prefer to point to a specific path for bash (a solution which may not be portable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the string up until the first `.so`, bash will happily handle it for you:

```
d1="${d%%.so*}.so"
```

The `${d%%.so*}` deletes the longest string from the right side `%%` of the variable `d` that matches `.so*`.  This effectively removes everything starting with `.so` until the end of the string.  We then manually re-add the `.so` we removed because `%%` removes the entire matched portion, not just the wildcard portion.

See this guide on [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) for more detail.

---

Alternately, you could use `sed` even though it would be considerably slower:

```
d1=$(sed 's/\(\.so\).*$/\1/' <<< $d)
```

Comment: Did you change this from `##` to `%%` and forgot to update the `##` in the text?

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Nope, I just can't type well today. :)

Answer (score 0):

When your `find` supports filenames as first parameter(s), you can use

```
find lib*so* | sed 's/\.so.*/.so/'
```